# Change Log location in ActiveMQ 5.15.0

Tags: java, logging, activemq-classic

I have downloaded and setup ActiveMQ 5.15.0 in my machine and followed [this guide](https://activemq.apache.org/getting-started).

I see that the logs location is in `apache-activemq-5.15.0-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.0\data\activemq.log`.

How do I change the location of this log file `\data` to a different file system?

Comment: Any feedback here? Did you get this sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.15.0 uses Log4j 1.x for logging, and the logging configuration is in `conf/log4j.properties`. See this line for the location of the main `activemq.log` file:

```
log4j.appender.logfile.file=${activemq.data}/activemq.log
```

You can change this to whatever path you like.

It's worth noting that ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.15.0 was released in June of 2017 (i.e. over 5 years ago now). I strongly recommend you upgrade to a more recent release, ideally [the latest](https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/download/).

Comment: Actually I am moving Active MQ from one server to different server, and i see that activeMQ log and conf are in a different file system in old server. since i need same setup i need to know how that ${activemq.data} attribute can be changed to point to different folder